# MySQL prevents server from booting unless password is entered

Tags: mysql, lamp

I am kind of new with Ubuntu but I have been working on setting up a LAMP server with hamachi as a vpn client for management.

The issue is that when we turn the server on or restart it we are required to enter the MySQL password before it will continue.

Where can we script a password or disable this? I have attached a partial of
`less /var/log/boot.log`

```
 * Starting MySQL ServerESC[204G[ OK ]
....... ok
Password:
```

If I haven't provided enough information please just comment and Ill try my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong in thinking MySQL was the issue. It was Hamachi, even if the network doesn't require a password, you must still give the command line one. I had to change my start-up script located at /etc/init.d/ to attempt a password

```
hamachi -c /etc/hamachi join (network #) blarg
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't need a password to start but it's probably rather MySQL trying to access a password protected SSL certificate, you can remove the password from the certificate and this should allow your server to start unmanned.

Comment: What services / where would I find the config file? I havent bought or installed a ssl cert.

Comment: it should be in /etc/mysql/my.conf search for ssl